# Pull JPlayer playlist element information

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm crushing my head for days, because I can't figure out how to show in a specific div/span the JPlayer playlist's current songs tite/name? I'm using the code from JPlayer's demo:

```
    var playlist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [
        {
            title:"Song - 1",
            mp3:"./path/to/song1.mp3"
        },
        {
            title:"Song - 2",
            mp3:"./path/to/song2.mp3"
        },
        ], {
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
```

Thanks for your help, guys! :)

Comment: Finally i've realized how to solve this problem. As i'm using the playlist version of the JPlayer, it makes an unsorted list (which i forgot, because i made its opacity 0) and there marks the current track with some special class. So i made a timed function, which checks if the playlist marking changed and if yes - copies the new title to the box i need. But while i was writing this i found out i can manipulate the playlist's display style, so i don't have to copy anything... :)

Answer (score 4):

In your jplayer.playlist.js file add a line like the following to the `_highlight` function with the correct `my_jquery_selector` for the div you'd like the title to be printed in:

```
$(my_jquery_selector).html(this.playlist[index].title);
```

This is jacked from the current final line of that method that sets the title div (`this.cssSelector.title`)in the player itself.

There are ways to get the title to show in the player itself but that doesn't seem to be what you are asking. I'm assuming here that you want to show the title in some div outside the player.

Answer (score 1):

To display only the current playing track, I just did this in the stylesheet:

```
div.jp-playlist ul li {
    display:none;
}

div.jp-playlist ul li.jp-playlist-current {
    display:inline;
}
```